# Giving Windows Service rights to move files to a remote directory that req. user/pass

Tags: c#, windows-services, active-directory

I'm using EWS to grab file attachments from emails in an inbox, and need to put those files (if they meet certain criteria) onto a network directory path that requires an active directory user/pass that is not the same as what the machine running the service is using.

There's probably multiple ways to attack this.  Without having to set that directory path to allow the user/pass that is running the windows service to have rights to read/write is there a way in code that I can set the user/pass before I try and place the files in that path?

In the installer setup of the windows service I've tried the following:

```
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User;
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = "password";
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = @"\\serverName\user";
```

when I try and install I get an error about mapping the user pass, so I tried this:

```
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.NetworkService;
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = "password";
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = @"\\serverName\user";
```

the installer works, the service shows up and I can start it, but when I debug/attach to the process it throws an exception when trying to write to the directory about access rights.

So maybe I'm not even attacking the right issue/section, as this is probably an active directory issue and something not done in code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

What you tried there is irrelevant to your problem.

If you're on windows 7, you may workaround by going to [Control Panel]->[User Accounts]->[Credential Manager] to store login information of target machines.